# Flat to nested JSON grouping on two properties

Tags: javascript, json

So my goal is create a hierarchy by forming a nested UL from JSON. I have accomplished this without too much difficulty; however, there are multiple employees that report to multiple supervisors. This causes there to be hundreds of extra HTML lists and list items that need to be grouped. So, my thought is to group employees by Title and Supervisor. Would it be best to try and restructure JSON before I use javascript to build the UL? I have spent a lot of time trying to determine the best approach, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Essentially, this is the JSON that is pulled from the server:

```
{ "name" : "A", "supervisor_title":"null", "title": "job_A", "extension":"1234"},
{ "name" : "B", "supervisor_title":"job_A", "title": "job_B", "extension":"2345"},
{ "name" : "C", "supervisor_title":"job_A", "title": "job_B", "extension":"3456"},
{ "name" : "D", "supervisor_title":"job_A", "title": "job_C", "extension":"4567"},
{ "name" : "E", "supervisor_title":"job_C", "title": "job_D", "extension":"5678"},
{ "name" : "F", "supervisor_title":"job_D", "title": "job_E", "extension":"6789"}
```

My thought is that if I nested the JSON into something like what is below, then I will be able to recursively build the UL without having the issues I currently have.

```
{"supervisor_title":"null", "title": "job_A", "employees":[
    { "name" : "A", "extension":"1234"}
] },
{"supervisor_title":"job_A", "title": "job_B", "employees":[
    {"name" : "B", "extension":"2345"},
    {"name" : "C", "extension":"3456"}
] },
{"supervisor_title":"job_A", "title": "job_C", "employees":[
     { "name" : "D", "extension":"4567"}
] },
{"supervisor_title":"job_C", "title": "job_D", "employees":[
     { "name" : "E", "extension":"5678"}
] },
{"supervisor_title":"job_D", "title": "job_E", "employees":[
    { "name" : "F", "extension":"6789"}
] }
```

I have figured out how to nest the JSON by "supervisor_title", but not both "supervisor_title" and "title". If any one can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Also, if there is a better way of doing this let me know.

Comment: try crossfilter https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference